# Failed to fetch 404 errors during apt-get commands

Tags: xenomai

I am using Xenomai linux, and I have internet on it, but when I do `apt-get update` or `apt-get install` I get [bunch of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LneUg.png) like this
`http://security.debian.org/dists/etch/updates/contrib/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]`

I understand it has to do with unsupported repositories, but I googled around, but couldn't find what I need to do to fix it for Xenomai.

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
   #
   # deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 4.0 r3 _Etch_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20080218-14:15]/ etch contrib main


   deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ etch main
   deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ etch main

   deb http://security.debian.org/ etch/updates main contrib
   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ etch/updates main contrib
```

Comment: so, what is your question? Those files aren't existing. 404 is expectable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/a/163893) answer, looks like support for etch ended a while ago. Try using the archive instead of using the Netherlands mirror.

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib
```